# Can functools.partial be used to bind arbitrary positional arguments?

Tags: python

Suppose you want to define a *partial* setting the positional arguments in an arbitrary order, i.e. you want to apply *partial* to *str.split* fixing the 2nd and 3th arguments. The desired result is the same as:

```
lambda s: str.rsplit(s, SEP, 1) # SEP given.
```

(I use `str.rsplit(s...` instead of `s.rsplit(...` to make the point more clear).

Some approximation using *functools.partial* is:

```
partial(str.rsplit, sep=SEP, maxsplit=1) # SEP given
```

But *str.rsplit* doesn't use keyword arguments, only positional.

How to fix those arguments in partial?
Are the only choices lamda and wrappers?

wrappers are ugly if you want to define the function inline, like defining it for an argument wating for a function. *Lambda* is the *defacto* here, and *partial* is the other option, but it seems to lack in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that with `partial`. This is because `split` uses the `PyArg_ParseTuple` function from the C API which doesn't provide keyword arguments. From the python's point of view it's like if the method was defined as:

```
def split(self, *args):
    if len(args) > 2:
        raise TypeError(...)
    sep = args[0] if args else None
    maxsplit = args[1] if len(args) > 1 else -1
    ...
```

Partial can only assign positional arguments in order. This is mentioned in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial), where they state that `partial` is "roughly equivalent to":

```
def partial(func, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = keywords.copy()
        newkeywords.update(fkeywords)
        return func(*(args + fargs), **newkeywords)
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc
```

Note the `return func(*(args + fargs), **newkeywords)` which clearly shows that the arguments you pass to `partial` are prepended to other function arguments.

The conclusion is that `lambda` are simply more powerful than `partial`.

On a side note, in python3.3 you can specify `maxsplit` as keyword argument:

```
>>> 'some string with spaces'.split(maxsplit=2)
['some', 'string', 'with spaces']
```

And the same goes for many other methods/functions that had the same issue.

Comment: Tanks! `return func(*(args + fargs), **newkeywords)` is the key.

Comment: Should expand your quite on-point remark re: lambdas to give an example for this case.

Answer (score 5):

For `str.rsplit` you really want to use [`operator.methodcaller()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller) instead:

```
>>> from operator import methodcaller
>>> SEP = ' '
>>> s = methodcaller('rsplit', SEP, 1)
>>> s('Test one two')
['Test one', 'two']
```